# How can I create a hidden ad-hoc network?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, wireless-access-point

My laptop is hooked up to a wired connection and that is the only way to access the network. So I setup a wireless access point on my laptop via network manager so my phone could connect to it (service is horrible here) and it works great. The problem now is that I would like to hide the SSID but can't find any where to do so in network manager or iwconfig. Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: The term "access point" has a [special meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point#Wireless_Access_Point_vs._Ad_Hoc_Network) with regard to computer networking that I think you don't intend here. I've edited your question with my interpretation, but please feel free to revert it if I've made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some searching online and it appears to me that it is not possible to hide the SSID, at least not if it's an ad-hoc network.

I think this might help explain it: http://lists.shmoo.com/pipermail/hostap/2008-August/018305.html